# Como logro que mi jpanel se ponga delante de otro JAVA

Tags: java, aplicación-escritorio

Estoy intentando hacer que mi jpanel se ponga delante del jtable cuando se de clic derecho sobre el jtable. Pero lo que me hace es que queda detrás de este como se ve en la imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la parte del codigo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco cualquier tipo de ayuda

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se puede optar por el uso del componente `JPopupMenu`, el cual está diseñado justamente para cubrir esa necesidad que planteas, de tal manera que por ejemplo:

```
JPopupMenu POP = new JPopupMenu();
JMenuItem DEL = new JMenuItem("Borrar");
JMenuItem SHOW = new JMenuItem("Mostrar");
POP.add(DEL);
POP.add(SHOW);

miTabla.addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter() {
  public void mousePressed( MouseEvent evt ) {
    if( evt.isPopupTrigger() ) {
      POP.show( miTabla, evt.getX(), evt.getY() );
    }
  }
} );
```

Pero quiero detenerme en lo siguiente, depende de cada sistema operativo como se despliega un menú contextual, quiero decir por ejemplo, Windows (no se si en todas las versiones vigentes) usa un evento de `mouseReleased` para mostrar opciones con el botón derecho pero en MacOS el evento es de `mousePressed`... Entonces lo aconsejable es implementar todos los métodos de `mouseListener`.

Finalmente `isPopupTrigger()` basicamente dice con un `boolean` si se ha presiondado el boton izquierdo (`false`) o si se ha hecho clic con el boton derecho (`true`).

Comment: Amigo muchas gracias, me haz sido de gran utilidad